# Pandas.read_excel using old data after save

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lengthy python code interfacing with excel using pandas.  My code opens the file, runs some VBA that updates a table in a sheet, saves the file, and then reads that table to a dataframe in python.  Everything runs smoothly, with the exception that the dataframe contains the data from when the file was opened, not after the changes and save were performed.  This is obviously a problem, and I've duplicated it on a second computer.  They are both running Windows 10, Office 2013, Python 3.5.2, and Pandas 0.18.1.  Any ideas as to how I can force Pandas to use current data in an open (saved) file?  Thanks in advance!

Here is a simple test I ran that duplicated the problem:

1. In a new Excel file (which remains open throughout the test), on Sheet1, I listed the numbers 1 through 26 downward starting in A1, and the capital letters A through Z, with the exception of a lower case m, from B1 downward.
2. I saved this file as "Test.xlsx" onto an external drive "I:".
3. I wrote a simple python code:

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   fpth = r'I:\Test.xlsx'
   df =  pd.read_excel(fpth,"Sheet1")
   print(df)
   ```

   which returns:

   ```
        1  A
   0    2  B
   1    3  C
   2    4  D
   3    5  E
   4    6  F
   5    7  G
   6    8  H
   7    9  I
   8   10  J
   9   11  K
   10  12  L
   11  13  m
   12  14  N
   13  15  O
   14  16  P
   15  17  Q
   16  18  R
   17  19  S
   18  20  T
   19  21  U
   20  22  V
   21  23  W
   22  24  X
   23  25  Y
   24  26  Z
   ```
4. Manually change the lower case m to upper case.
5. Save the workbook.
6. Run python code again.

It returns the old dataframe, with a lower case m, not my updated and saved version.

Comment: Can you show how you *runs some VBA that updates a table in a sheet*?

Comment: The VBA turns out to be just irrelevant background info.  In trying to duplicate the problem, manually adding data to the range (either by continuing at the bottom or by inserting a row) and reading the sheet to a dataframe after saving results in the same problem of returning the data from when the file was opened (whether I had python open it or opened it manually before running the code).

Comment: Please describe these numbered steps to reproduce your problem including all relevant code and do so in your post and not comments.

Comment: I just tried this and did not have any problem.  Might be some kind of system cache-ing that has nothing to do with python or pandas?  I am on a windows machine at the moment btw.  Probably you can work around by making a copy or closing/re-opening the file, etc.  I don't see any option in read_excel that would force a re-load of the file (again, this is maybe more of a system thing than python thing)

Answer (score -1):

This simple workaround has been good for me. I have the same problem on large files sometimes - it's inconsistent. (windows 10, office365, updated regularly, on local C disk).

1. After saving the file in Excel, use Windows File Explorer to copy the file to a different name say 'Test - Copy.xlsx'
2. In python, open the copy

```
import pandas as pd

fpth = r'I:\Test - Copy.xlsx'
df =  pd.read_excel(fpth,"Sheet1")
print(df)
```

Not a nice solution, but your question and a similar one from 5 years ago are unanswered, so I hope this helps someone.